# Windows 2003 Server can connect to the netwerk, but no client can connect to this server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

I have a Windows 2003 Server (AD) running and after updating the server with the latest MS patches the server cannot be seen on the network anymore. The clients cannot ping it, access the http server or access the file shares anymore. However, the server can ping the clients, see file shares of other servers and access the internet.

If checekd the following:

- There is no firewall running, nor is IP filtering enabled
- The Virus Scanner is removed
- The IP address is stil the same and static
- File and Printer Sharing is turned on

No other machine can ping/access it. I'm on connecting to the server using a simple switch without any firewall.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is Network Discovery turned on?

Comment: Network Discovery doesn't exist in Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Can other machines on the same network/LAN ping/access it? Perhaps there's a firewall at the router level?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @joeqwerty, what I mean to say is "File and Print Sharing" is turned on. See this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc181373.aspx) about ICMP and other connectivity related functions lumped in with "File and Print Sharing"

Comment: @out-null Yes, File and Printer sharing is enabled (same as before the windows updates)

Comment: @barrycarter No other machine can ping/access it. I'm on connecting to the server using a simple switch without any firewall. It very much looks like some firewall blocking the traffic, but I cannot think of anything causing this.

Comment: I might try turning windows firewall on and see if you can ping it. I've seen strange settings where it is turned off, but is still having an effect on a server.

Comment: @Nixphoe That was it! This resolved the problem. Really counter intuitive. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might try turning windows firewall on and see if you can ping it. I've seen strange settings where it is turned off, but is still having an effect on a server.